# AVPlayer created from Cloudfront URL doesn't like to load on cellular data

Tags: swift, amazon-cloudfront, avplayer

So I'm loading videos from an AWS S3 bucket, but it takes forever to load when I'm on LTE (as opposed to wifi). Is this common? It seems to vary from device to device. Some devices load a 20 second video in like a few seconds while on LTE, while other devices will be loading for > 30 seconds. What could be causing the discrepancy? Hardware, mobile device internet plan? Something else? How can I optimize load times?

For an example, how does TikTok load videos with limited/no buffer time while on only LTE? This is the behavior I am trying to mimic.

Comment: Hello ! 

Did you find any solution? Do you protect your AWS files in anyway ? Or are they public?